# How to get sord,sidx,page,rows,_serach values to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, jqgrid

I getting null values for the fields sord, sidx,page,rows,_serach etc from JQ Grid while calling controller. I have posted my code.I need to do server side coding for sort,search and to set the rownum count dynamically.Any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayGrid() {
        $("#JQGridServerSideTable").jqGrid({
             width: 750,
            height: '100%',
            url: '@Url.Action("ServerSideJqGridProcessing", "JQGridHome")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames:  ["Application ID", "TenantId", "Application Name"],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'AppId', index: 'AppId', hidden: false },
            { name: 'TenantId', index: 'TenantId', resizable: true, align: 'center', title: false, editable: true, sortable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'le', 'lt', 'gt', 'ge'] }, searchtype: "number",editrules: {required: true, number: true} },
            { name: 'AppName', index: 'AppName', sortable: true, editable: true,editrules: {required: true} },
            ],  
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#JQGridServerSidePaging',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Application List Details",
            sortname: "TenantId",
            sortorder: "asc",
            hoverrows: true,
            altRows:true,
            altclass:'myAltRowClass',
            hidegrid: true,
            toppager: false,
            multiselect: false,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            loadtext:'Loading Data please wait ...'

        });
        $("#JQGridServerSideTable").jqGrid('navGrid', '#JQGridServerSidePaging',
             {
                refresh: false, add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: true,
                searchtext: "Search",
             },
             {},
             {},{},

             {
              sopt: ['eq', 'cn', 'lt', 'le', 'bw', 'bn', 'in'], closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, overlay: true, width: 460, closeAfterSearch: true }
         );
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        displayGrid();
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ServerSideJqGridProcessing(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string searchField, string searchOper, string searchString)
{
     AllApps o = new AllApps();
     ApplicationModel appModelObj = new ApplicationModel();
     List<AppList> groups = o.getAllAppList();
     List<AppList> result = null;
     if (_search)
     {
         result = groups.Where(x => x.AppName.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
     }
     else
     {
         result = groups.Skip(page * rows).Take(rows).ToList();
     }
     int i = 1;
     var jsonData = new { 
         total = groups.Count,
         page = page,
         records = groups.Count,
         rows = (from appgroup in result
                 select new {
                     i=i++,
                     cell = new string[]{appgroup.AppName,appgroup.AppId.ToString(),appgroup.TenantId.ToString()}
                 }).ToArray()
     };
     int TotalCount = appModelObj.AllApplicationList.Count;
     return Json(jsonData);
}
```

Comment: I would try to break the grid down property by property until the basic functionality starts to work just passing down sord, sidx,page,rows. After this works add just filters param and see if its comming down, etc. keep column models simple for starters, do it step by step. BTW: how does get request look like in network of dev tools? Are there any console errors?

Comment: It's hitting the controller in the controller iam getting null values for all the arguments. There is no error with java script.

Comment: I mean how does the query string in network look like is it malformed or does it have proper query param structure?

Comment: What happens if you add -> contentType: 'application/json' to your jqGrid call? You set datatype to json, but I see no content type

Comment: ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }   I added this code Iam getting the values now but for rows iam getting rows:[]  as response

Comment: Have you tried to make the request via POST (mtype: "POST")?